# CentOS port forwarding not working

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I'm using CentOS 6.5 and I added the following commands to my iptables to forward all incoming traffic on port 8088 to 4569:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp --dport 8088 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4569
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 127.0.0.1 -p udp --dport 4569 -j ACCEPT
```

`iptables --list` shows the following output:

```
iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             localhost.localdomain udp dpt:iax

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

But when I take a packet trace on udp port 4569 I don't see any packets on that port. Then I added this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp --dport 8088 -i eth0 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4569
```

And my iptable looks like this:

```
Table: nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:8088 to:127.0.0.1:4569
2    REDIRECT   udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:8088 redir ports 4569
```

But still no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To redirect packets to the loopback interface you need to use the `REDIRECT` target.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp --dport 8088 -i eth0 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4569
```

Otherwise, you will change the destination address before the routing decision is taken to `127.0.0.1`. This means that it will be considered a **martian packet** by the kernel and dropped by your reverse path filtering policy.

The two kernel parameters responsible for this behaviour are :

- `net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet`

> route_localnet - BOOLEAN
>
> Do not consider loopback addresses as martian source or destination
>       while routing. This enables the use of 127/8 for local routing purposes.
>
> default FALSE

- `net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter`

> rp_filter - INTEGER
>
> 0 - No source validation.
>      1 - Strict mode as
>   defined in RFC3704 Strict Reverse Path
>         Each incoming packet is tested against the FIB and if the interface
>         is not the best reverse path the packet check will fail.
>         By default failed packets are discarded.
>      2 - Loose mode as defined in RFC3704 Loose Reverse Path
>         Each incoming packet's source address is also tested against the FIB
>         and if the source address is not reachable via any interface
>         the packet check will fail.
>
> Current recommended practice in RFC3704 is to enable strict mode    to
>   prevent IP spoofing from DDos attacks. If using asymmetric routing    or
>   other complicated routing, then loose mode is recommended.
>
> The max value from conf/{all,interface}/rp_filter is used   when doing
>   source validation on the {interface}.
>
> Default value is 0. Note that some distributions enable it  in
>   startup scripts.

As you totally want to keep this legitimate behaviour, the `REDIRECT` chain must be used to bypass this condition for a certain rule.

Comment: Tried but no luck. Please check my updated question.

Comment: @user3360140 Why did you let the DNAT rule ? It's the only one reached as you appended the REDIRECT rule after it ...

Answer (score -1):

You may need to enable ip forwarding in the Linux kernel.

First, check the current value.

> sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward

A zero means ip forwarding is disabled. This is the default.

Enable ip forwarding.

> sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Now, retest.